# Get current row table ADF

Tags: java, arraylist, binding, oracle-adf

I have Array list in page Flow Scope.

```
 List<EtaxDetail> lstEtaxDetail
```

Then, I bind it to table.

```
<af:table value="#{pageFlowScope.ABCBean.lstEtaxDetail}">
```

When binding by ViewIterator, I used code:

```
 DCIteratorBinding dcIterACCTNO = ADFUtils.findIterator("");
 ViewObject vo = dcIterACCTNO.getViewObject();
 Row cRow = vo.getCurrentRow();
```

How can I get current selected row in this table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide your own `SelectionListener` on your `af:table`.
Great examples can be found [here](http://soadev.blogspot.be/2013/05/simple-tables.html) or [here](http://rohanwalia.blogspot.be/2015/01/custom-selection-listener-for-adf-table.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
    DCBindingContainer bindings = this.getDCBindingContainer();
    DCIteratorBinding itorBinding =
   bindings.findIteratorBinding("XxbecErrConsoleLinesStgView1Iterator");//ur iterator name
    RowSetIterator rsi = itorBinding.getRowSetIterator();
    ViewObject ioOrderLines= itorBinding.getViewObject();
    if(itorBinding!= null){
            Row currentRow = itorBinding.getCurrentRow();
            if(currentRow != null){
           obj=currentRow.getAttribute("InterfaceHeaderId");//ur column name which u want to fetch
           System.out.println(currentRow.getAttribute("InterfaceHeaderId"));
            }}
```

//and the code for the `getDCBindingContainer()` method code is -->

```
public DCBindingContainer getDCBindingContainer() {
    DCBindingContainer bindingsContainer =
        (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry(); 
    return bindingsContainer;
```